# UIWebView: delete cookies of a specified webview

Tags: iphone, cookies, ios6, uiwebview

I have two web views in which I want two run two different facebook accounts on both of these webviews. However, if I sign in on one webview the other webview automatically signs in as well as these two webviews share the same cookies. I know I can delete cookies by using the piece of code that gets a deletes all cookies.
However, this deletes the cookies of both webviews. So is there a way to delete the cookies of only one webview? Or maybe an alternate way of accomplishing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work, since both the `UIWebView` will share the same cookies.

`UIWebView` cookies and cache are shared with the App, each app has it own cookies and cache stored with the apps sandbox. There is no way to change it behavior.

Comment: Well do you know of any alternate way of accomplishing this without using cookies. Because I know it's possible since the google chrome app used different instances of webviews within the same app with tabs being one instance and incognito tabs